# Getting count of records in child table using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in which i am trying to select all the columns of a table Table 1. There is another table which uses Table1 primary key as foreign key. I want to count number of records in this foreign key table with that select like this:

```
SELECT *, count(*) VacancyCount
    FROM Table1 hc
    LEFT JOIN Table2 hv
    on hc.CompanyID = hv.CompanyID  
    WHERE hc.Deleted = 0
    group by hc.CompanyID
    ORDER BY NameLang1
```

but it gives error:

> Column 'dbo.Table1.NameLang1' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Please suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    *,
    (select COUNT(*) from Table2 hv where hv.CompanyID=hc.CompanyID) VacancyCount
from Table1 hc
where
    hc.Deleted = 0
order by hc.NameLang1, VacancyCount desc
```

for ordering using the new column

```
select * from(
    select 
        *,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), (select COUNT(*) from Table2 hv where hv.CompanyID=hc.CompanyID)) VacancyCount
    from Table1 hc
    where
        hc.Deleted = 0
)x
Order by CASE WHEN @OrderByParam = 1 THEN NameLang1 ELSE VacancyCount END
```

Provided column `NameLang1` and `VacancyCount` are of same datatype.

Comment: Can we order by results using count ?

Comment: Yea... sure... U can add `VacancyCount desc` or `VacancyCount asc`.

Comment: techdo: I am trying this Order by
 CASE WHEN @OrderByParam = 1 THEN NameLang1 ELSE VacancyCount END but it says invalid column VacancyCount

Comment: Inside the case condition, you wont get the alias column name `VacancyCount`. For that you need to make it as a block.

Comment: I used it but it says: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure hr_Companies_GetList, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'my company1aa' to data type int.   and i see that my company1aa is a value of column used in order by clause NameLang1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29978/discussion-between-techdo-and-dotnetsparrow)

Comment: This adding an inline select count statement causes serious performance issues for me.  It now takes several minutes for a statement that worked in 0.003 seconds previously.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, this will most likely result in sub-select on `Table2` being executed for every row of `Table1`, which is bad if `Table1` is large.

Answer (score 7):

You're doing grouping wrong. You need to use all the columns from Table 1 in SELECT instead of '*' and in GROUP BY clause as well.

Or you can try a different approach like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 hc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table2 GROUP BY CompanyID) hv
on hc.CompanyID = hv.CompanyID  
WHERE hc.Deleted = 0
ORDER BY NameLang1
```

Comment: Can we order by results using cnt ?

Comment: Of course, it becomes an ordinary column when wrapped as a subquery and can be used in any clause (including order by).

Comment: I am using techdo answer but when i use Order by
 CASE WHEN @OrderByParam = 1 THEN NameLang1 ELSE VacancyCount END it says invalid column VacancyCount

Comment: Because it's not inside the subquery (the alias) in his answer, but it is in my one, that's why you're getting an exception. Oracle doesn't know about the column name (read alias) before completing the query and since subqeries are performed before main ones, it's allowed to use aliases used in subqueries as names of tables' columns in order by clause.

Comment: And by the way, the way which was suggested by @techdo is not as efficient in performance terms, there for each row in Table1 a subquery is performed, but in my example there's only one subquery execution and one join operations which's much faster.

Comment: much faster than outer apply

Answer (score 2):

You will have to list every column in the GROUP BY clause
These columns are those in the `SELECT *` bit.

This would be correct ANSI SQL anyway.

`SELECT *` itself is bad anyway: it is always better to explicitly list columns

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way include column list in group by

```
 SELECT column1,column2,column3..,NameLang1,count(*) VacancyCount
FROM Table1 hc
LEFT JOIN Table2 hv
on hc.CompanyID = hv.CompanyID  
WHERE hc.Deleted = 0
group by column1,column2,column3
ORDER BY NameLang1
```